# Can overflowed content affect window.innerWidth?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, viewport

So the [definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-window-innerwidth) of `innerWidth` according to W3C is:

> The innerWidth attribute must return the viewport width **including the size of a rendered scroll bar** (if any), or zero if there is no viewport.

Does this mean that if something inside the document generates overflow then `window.innerWidth` can be affected? I have this very simple [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/window-inner-width-test-0t24y) (which is only a div causing overflow) and this seems to be true when using the [sandbox preview](https://0t24y.csb.app/) with Chrome device tools (Chromium 84) and in mobile (I only tested Android), but in desktop browsers the value doesn't seem to be affected. Why? Is this the intended behavior?.

Note in the image that the width in the tools don't match the logged width:

[image: Width mismatch preview]

Comment: It only overflows if the content is wider than the window. Content can be wider than the window when text does not break or when the actual width is wider. I personally set my overflow on everything with `*{ overflow:hidden; }`, unless I specifically want to add scroll bars. That's my two cent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, overflowed content cannot affect `window.innerWidth`. What you are seeing is an issue with chrome dev tools. The window is still 1600px even though chrome is artificially resizing to a mobile device size.

[image]